# Erro com a função lapply

Tags: r

Tento executar a seguinte função:

```
result<-lapply(mylist,function(x)cbind(x,var=tapply(x[,c(3)],x[,c(1)],sum)))
```

Mas, surge este erro:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 340623, 63073
```

Preciso retornar a soma dentro dos dataframes para a minha lista. Qual é o problema com a fórmula?

**Infelizmente não posso compartilhar os dados para auxiliar a resposta**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem os dados fica muito complicado replicar o problema que você está encontrando. Utilizando a estrutura que você já postou em outras dúvidas

```
mylist
[[1]]
     number group      sexo
1  26.12186     a Masculino
2  40.39104     a Masculino
3  29.29426     a Masculino
4  45.11651     b  Feminino
5  26.72512     b Masculino
6  45.95550     b Masculino
7  47.56538     c  Feminino
8  43.14062     c  Feminino
9  47.42608     c Masculino
10 23.57519     c  Feminino

[[2]]
     number group      sexo
1  47.64770     a Masculino
2  22.61412     a  Feminino
3  48.37883     a Masculino
4  48.44754     b Masculino
5  41.67047     b  Feminino
6  23.74823     b Masculino
7  28.82786     c Masculino
8  30.12309     c  Feminino
9  27.12305     c Masculino
10 49.58259     c  Feminino
11 40.21284     d Masculino
12 40.57279     d  Feminino
13 48.33335     d Masculino
14 22.92160     d Masculino
15 25.07216     e Masculino
```

Fui fazendo o que você deseja passo-a-passo. Ao rodar a função `tapply` você vai obter um `array` com duas colunas e uma linha, que vai ser a soma dos valores por sexo:

```
tapply(mylist[[1]][,1], mylist[[1]][,3], sum)
 Feminino Masculino 
 159.3977  215.9139
```

Por isso que o erro está aparecendo, ao ser executado o comando `cbind` ele tenta concatenar um `data.frame` com um número de linhas diferente do resultado do `tapply`.

Para contornar esse problema e entendendo que o que você deseja seja colocar o valor da soma dos sexos como uma nova variável, você pode se  basear no seguinte código:

```
teste <- mylist[[1]]
teste1 <- tapply(teste[,1], teste[,3], sum)
teste2 <- tidyr::gather(data.frame(teste1), key = "sexo")
teste2$sexo <- names(teste1)

dplyr::left_join(teste, teste2)
Joining, by = "sexo"
 number group      sexo    value
1  26.12186     a Masculino 215.9139
2  40.39104     a Masculino 215.9139
3  29.29426     a Masculino 215.9139
4  45.11651     b  Feminino 159.3977
5  26.72512     b Masculino 215.9139
6  45.95550     b Masculino 215.9139
7  47.56538     c  Feminino 159.3977
8  43.14062     c  Feminino 159.3977
9  47.42608     c Masculino 215.9139
10 23.57519     c  Feminino 159.3977
```

Rodei só o primeiro `data.frame` da lista justamente para tentar entender o problema.